# Apple Music & Apple TV

Tags: appletv, apple-music

As far as I can see Apple TV does not support Apple Music (see [Apple Music](https://www.apple.com/music/))

[image]

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Music will launch on iOS, Mac, and Windows on June 30, coming to Apple TV and Android phones this fall. Here is the news you can check. http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2015/06/08Introducing-Apple-Music-All-The-Ways-You-Love-Music-All-in-One-Place-.html

Comment: Hi thanks! I edited your link with the official Apple announcement that was linked in the article. Sad that Apple mentions Android and not its own products in the main page ...